# localparam after wire declaration

Tags: verilog

For a very strange reason (scripts we use) I need to be able to declare a localparam AFTER I declare wires and regs in a module:

```
module blah (clk, rst, in, out);

  input        clk;
  input        rst;
  input  [2:0] in;
  output [3:0] out;

  wire         res;

  localparam NUMBER=5;


...
```

is this legal verilog code? I would also appreciate a link to the relevant seciton in the documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is valid Verilog (2001). Verilog 2001 saw the introduction of `localparam`, for all versions it is still syntactically valid to use parameter in this context. `localparam` indicates that it can not be overridden.

Usage can be seen in section **23.10 Overriding module parameters** of [SystemVerilog IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf).

From IEEE 1800-2012:

For example:

```
module generic_fifo
    #(MSB=3, LSB=0)        // parameter port list parameters
    (input  wire  [MSB:LSB] in,
     input  wire            clk, read, write, reset,
     output logic [MSB:LSB] out,
     output logic           full, empty );

  parameter   DEPTH=4; // module item parameter

  localparam FIFO_MSB = DEPTH*MSB;
  localparam FIFO_LSB = LSB;
    // These constants are local, and cannot be overridden.
    // They can be affected by altering the value parameters above

  logic [FIFO_MSB:FIFO_LSB] fifo;
  logic [LOG2(DEPTH):0] depth;

  always @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
    casez ({read,write,reset})
      // implementation of fifo
    endcase
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly. As per the [Verilog IEEE Std 1364-2001](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs150/fa06/Labs/verilog-ieee.pdf), you can use localparam in your Verilog code. It can be declared after wire declaration, no problem for that.