# Modelsim: wrong scope for localparam

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm trying to compile following code in Modelsim:

```
    module ctrl_mem
    #(
        parameter BYTE_SIZE = 256
    )
    (
        input [ADDR_W - 1 : 0]  i_addr,
        ...
        ...
    );
    localparam ADDR_W = $clog2(BYTE_SIZE);
```

Modelsim writes that ADDR_W is unknown.
Similar question was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724904/localparam-after-wire-declaration) but Modelsim behavior is not covered there and unfortunately I cannot comment it to ask this question.

Is it possible to fix this issue without code modification?

I use Modelsim Altera Starter Edition 10.3c

Comment: This question was discussed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.verilog/B8ZDqcGAFV8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is not legal. The Verilog/SystemVerilog LRM requires that simple identifiers (those not followed by a '**.**' or '**(**') be declared prior to being referenced. The correct way to write this module is

```
 module ctrl_mem
    #(
        parameter BYTE_SIZE = 256, localparam ADDR_W = $clog2(BYTE_SIZE)
    )
    (
        input [ADDR_W - 1 : 0]  i_addr,
        ...
        ...
    );
```

Comment: Hi Dave! I have already tried this option. Unfortunately it doesn't work in Quartus: Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at ctrl_ram.sv(40) near text "localparam";  expecting an identifier ("localparam" is a reserved keyword ). And in fact original code works in Quartus but doesn't work in ModelSim.

Comment: Currently I'm using old style for module definition: `module ctrl_mem (i_addr, ...); parameter BYTE_SIZE = 256; localparam ADDR_W = $clog2(BYTE_SIZE); input [ADDR_W - 1 : 0]  i_addr; ` But I would prefer to use new style if possible

Comment: Then I guess you are stuck with the old-style (non-Ansi) syntax until Quartus fixes their compiler, or you could not use a localparam at all. (write the equation in-line or use a `define)

Comment: @Siarhei  Be sure to file a [service request with Altera](https://www.altera.com/support.html) so they can see that there is demand for this feature.

Comment: @Chiggs Posted request

Comment: @Chiggs I sent one to Cadence as well since this does not appear supported in Incisive either.  I had always just assumed it wasn't legal syntax!

Comment: @nguthrie me too - none of my tools support this syntax.  Found it very annoying having to use `parameter` and leave your IP open to the possibility that users could override derived params that should be local.

Comment: This is the answer from Altera: For your information, this syntax is not yet supported in our compiler and I’ve feedback to our internal team for enhancement request.

Answer (score 0):

As you discovered, the newer style parameter declaration ("module_parameter_port_list" in the LRM syntax definition) only supports parameters and not localparams, and as has been mentioned it needs to be declared before it's used, so this leaves you with the option of either using the old-style syntax, or using `parameter`.

Whenever I have an I/O width dependent on a constant derived from another parameter that I want to be able to override, I always used `parameter` for this reason.  They way I think of it, a case like this is not necessarily a good candidate for '`localparam`', as it's not truly/completely "local" -- you are using it to specify the width of an interface signal thus exposed outside the module.  At least that's how I explain the situation to myself.

Comment: You are right. I agree that this value is not completely local, so it is better to use `parameter` instead of `localparam`. Thanks

Comment: This answer is not correct. See Example 3 in section 23.2.3 Parameterized modules of the IEEE 1800-2012 LRM

Comment: Agree with Dave. One additional feature is that the word `parameter` is absent in that example.